# How do I repair exterior window casing after burglar bar removal?

Tags: windows, window-frame

A previous contractor damaged the exterior wood casing around a vinyl replacement window while removing burglar bars. The window is now quite drafty and there may be some moisture ingress as well. What are my options for repairing the damage or replacing the casing entirely?

A few options I have considered so far:

- patch holes with wood filler, reseal edges with silicone caulk
- cut around damaged areas, patch with fresh lumber, reseal w/ caulk
- replace or cover over with a vinyl casing replacement

Given the nature of this damage, are there any other window components that may require repair? E.g. flashing

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's hard to tell much from that image, but I'd suggest that

1. Yes, it's probably safe to assume there's other damage. Inspect carefully.
2. Covering the casing will allow it to rot without you ever knowing and will be loud! We have aluminum covered window casing and I hate it - rain drops sound like they're *pounding* on the covers - vinyl would be quieter but still...

3. You can patch holes, but the bigger the hole, the more effort it will take to get it right. I can't tell how big those holes are from this image.

   - If they're big enough, you could drill them out slightly to match the diameter of the next larger size of dowel and fill them with a dowel. Much better quality patch than trying to fill a large hole with wood filler.
4. Patching in new wood to replace a section with several holes is a good idea, but it needs to be a snug fitting patch to ensure no water works it's way through the joints and gets behind the wood, rotting it from the back side. I've done this for a couple of interior pieces, but never exterior.
5. Full replacement of all the casings is probably the "gold standard" answer, but is also the most expensive and time consuming.

Comment: Thanks. My repairs will probably require a mix of wood dowels for smaller holes at the top and new wood patches for the larger damage near the bottom.

For new wood patches, do you recommend wood glue for a snug fit at the joints? I've also read that an angled joint, sloping down to the exterior, will help keep moisture out.

When installing the patches, should I apply anything underneath the new wood to help with waterproofing or air sealing? E.g. caulk, brick/mortar sealant, or expanding foam

Comment: Absolutely glue in any patches! Be sure to use a water resistant/proof glue, like Titebond™ III or similar. If you can bevel the cuts so that any moisture that might get into the joint has a nice, downhill path to get out, that's definitely a good option. As you pull a piece out that you're replacing, take a look at what's between the wood & brick - that'll give you an idea of how it was waterproofed/flashed to begin with - you'll probably want to replicate that. If you have additional questions about that, please [ask a whole new question](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/ask).

Answer (score 0):

Get some epoxy based wood filler to double as an adhesive for filling that bit of delamination down low. After sneaking some inside the delaminated area, wedge a chunk of wood across there to close the gap as well as possible. Now strike the surface flat. The rest of the holes are easy to handle in one go with the epoxy based wood filler.

Prime and paint. Paint is the best protection to avoid further weather damage, so stay on top of that maintenance. It doesn't look like the delaminated area can survive much more exposure.